# LongListSelector get selected data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I need to get the selected data from longlistselector but normal code not work

xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" DataContext="{Binding listData}" IsGroupingEnabled="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,10" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImgUrl}" Height="70" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImgText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

c#:

```
    ObservableCollection<LongListData> listData = new ObservableCollection<LongListData>();
    listData.Add(new LongListData() { ImgText = "Imafsdfsge1", ImgUrl = new Uri("Assets/chart.png", UriKind.Relative) });     
MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = listData;
```

but on event:

```
private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

messagebox say: +longlistdata

why?

the list work perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the selecteditem to the custom object that you are binding to,

```
private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selecteditem = MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as LongListData; 
            MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.ImgText.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: @user3477026 mark it as an answer so it may help others in future

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are calling the `ToString()` method of the selected item which is of type `LongListData` if you want to show the `ImgText` you would need to do `MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem.ImgText` 
or you could override the `ToString()`method and implement your own logic.

Comment: "ImgText" not exist on SelectedItem. and Visul Studio return error

Comment: it's possible you need to cast it to `LongListData` first

Answer (score 0):

As per my guess you want to show the text associated with image in your messagebox. i.e 'Imafsdfsge1'

To get this try

```
var item = (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem as LongListData;
MessageBox.Show(item.SelectedItem.ImgText.ToString()); // output "Imafsdfsge1"
```